# How to send input between screens in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

how can I send input from one screen to another screen.In class Create I set input2 to ObjectProperty.I just want to send that input2 to screen All, that I can set  input2 to ObjectProperty in screen All .Is there some library or function to do it.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Thanks
My python file:

```
Builder.load_file("main.kv")
db = TinyDB("storing.json")
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size=(400,600)
Window.clearcolor = (214/255, 201/255, 78/255, 1)
class MainWindow(Screen, FloatLayout):
    def submit(self):
        self.manager.current = "all"
class Create(Screen, FloatLayout):
    input1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    input2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Create, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text_store = JsonStore('storing.json')
        print('loading...')
    def give(self):
        self.text_store['1'] = {self.input2.text:self.input1.text}
class All(Screen,FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(All, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text_store = JsonStore('storing.json')

class Notes(App):
    title = "NOTES"
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name="main"))
        sm.add_widget(Create(name="create"))
        sm.add_widget(All(name="all"))
        return sm
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Notes().run()
```

My kv. file:

```
<MainWindow>:
    name:"main"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba : 255,255,255,1
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos:(95, 450)
            size : 210,120
            radius: [30, 30, 30, 30]
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text:"NOTES"
            pos:(100,450)
            size_hint:(.5,.2)
            color:0,0,0,1
        Button:
            text:"NEW NOTE"
            pos :(100, 300)
            size_hint : (.5,.2)
            on_release:app.root.current="create"
        Button:
            text:"ALL NOTES"
            pos :(100, 180)
            size_hint : (.5,.2)
            on_release:app.root.current="all"
        Button:
            text:"EXIT"
            pos :(100, 60)
            size_hint : (.5,.2)
            on_release:app.stop()
<Create>:
    name:"create"
    input1 : input1
    input2 : input2
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text:"NOTE NAME:"
            pos_hint:{"x":0.07,"top":.95}
            size_hint : (.1,0.05)
        TextInput:
            id : input1
            multiline:True
            pos_hint :{"x":.1,"top":.8}
            size_hint : (.8,.4)
            on_text:
                root.give()
        TextInput:
            id:input2
            multiline : False
            pos_hint:{"x":.25,"top":.95}
            size_hint:(.4,0.05)
        Button:
            id:"submit"
            text:"SUBMIT"
            pos_hint :{"x":.25,"top":.4}
            size_hint : (.5,.2)
            on_release:
                app.root.current="all"


        Button:
            id:"back"
            text:"BACK"
            pos_hint :{"x":.25,"top":.2}
            size_hint : (.5,.2)
            on_release:app.root.current="main"
<All>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text:"back"
            size_hint:(1,.2)
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"top":.2}
            on_release:app.root.current="main"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the `TextInput` info when the `All` `Screen` is displayed by adding an `on_enter()` method, like this:

```
class All(Screen,FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(All, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text_store = JsonStore('storing.json')

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.lab.text = self.manager.get_screen('create').input2.text
```

Just to display the transferred text, I added a `Label` to the `All` `Screen`:

```
<All>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text:"back"
            size_hint:(1,.2)
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"top":.2}
            on_release:app.root.current="main"
        Label:
            id: lab
            text: 'None'
            size_hint: .1, .1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':1}
```

Comment: can I add that label in method in python code(that label will have the id = lab), it didn't work to me

Comment: No, `ids` are only assigned in `kv`.